# How to add an android Searchbar1

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar, searchview

I was wondering if anyone could break down for me step by step how to add a searchbar in an activity .

I have tried to look it up online but I couldn't really understand how it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this dependency in your gradle :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.0.0'
}
```

Add this to your Mani Activity:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary" />

    <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Create a menu file:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/abc_search_hint"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Add this to your MainActivity:

```
MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Do some magic
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //Do some magic
            return false;
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {
            //Do some magic
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {
            //Do some magic
        }
    });
```

Here is OnActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MaterialSearchView.REQUEST_VOICE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        if (matches != null && matches.size() > 0) {
            String searchWrd = matches.get(0);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(searchWrd)) {
                searchView.setQuery(searchWrd, false);
            }
        }

        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Create some array list in string res:

```
<string-array name="query_suggestions">
    <item>Android</item>
    <item>iOS</item>
    <item>SCALA</item>
    <item>Ruby</item>
    <item>JavaScript</item>
</string-array>
```

Add the string res to search textbox:

```
searchView.setSuggestions(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.query_suggestions));
```

Answer (score 0):

add a new menu file and name it as res/menu/menu_search.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
            android:title="@string/hint_search"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Once we create a menu file, we're going to load it in the MainActivity like described below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
        implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;
    }
```