# Drop down list in SearchView

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

I'm creating activity like on the screen. I read many tutorials about SearchView in toolbar and implemented it in my activity and it works(code above). But how to make this drop down list? Thanks for ideas, links or code.

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second_activity_menu, menu);


        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.second_toolbar_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
       // ...
   }
```

[image: Activity I need to create]

Comment: use and autocomplete text view https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: use [this](https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch) library its open source

Comment: use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39200200/4907554)

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency in your gradle :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.0.0'
}
```

Add this to your Main Activity:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary" />

    <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Create a menu file:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/abc_search_hint"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Add this to your MainActivity:

```
MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Do some magic
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //Do some magic
            return false;
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {
            //Do some magic
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {
            //Do some magic
        }
    });
```

Here is OnActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MaterialSearchView.REQUEST_VOICE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        if (matches != null && matches.size() > 0) {
            String searchWrd = matches.get(0);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(searchWrd)) {
                searchView.setQuery(searchWrd, false);
            }
        }

        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Create some array list in string res:

```
<string-array name="query_suggestions">
    <item>Android</item>
    <item>iOS</item>
    <item>SCALA</item>
    <item>Ruby</item>
    <item>JavaScript</item>
</string-array>
```

Add the string res to search textbox:

```
searchView.setSuggestions(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.query_suggestions));
```